# Decompiling Unity IEnumerator correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, decompiling

is there any way to decompile Unity IEnumerators,Coroutines?
or any application including not free ones
Decompiling using dnSPY or ILSPY Generate Unity IEnumerators like this

```
[DebuggerHidden]
private IEnumerator get_buy_steam_finish(ulong orderID)
{
Shop.<get_buy_steam_finish>c__Iterator31 <get_buy_steam_finish>c__Iterator = new Shop.<get_buy_steam_finish>c__Iterator31();
<get_buy_steam_finish>c__Iterator.orderID = orderID;
<get_buy_steam_finish>c__Iterator.<$>orderID = orderID;
<get_buy_steam_finish>c__Iterator.<>f__this = this;
return <get_buy_steam_finish>c__Iterator;
}
```

It generate `c_Iterator` which is not valid at all

Comment: You cannot do that without additional information (such as debugging symbols - but I don't know any decompiler that understands mono symbols).

Comment: Requests for tools is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: If you are still struggling with this - try dotPeek from JetBrains. When installed - go to Tools > Options and uncheck "Show compiler-generated code" (if it's checked). Then it might be able to decompile your iterators.